# Calculation errors

Tags: java, android

Ok,

So I'm hoping this should be quite a simple problem for someone out there.

The program works just fine, no errors, no crashes so thats a good start!

The problem is I'm getting an incorrect answer.

About half way down you should be able to see the line

`CARV= CA*3; tv2.setText(Double.toString(CARV));`

`CA` relates to `num3`, which is a user input. so if the user inputs 100 in `editText2` it should print 300 to `tv2`. But instead it is giving me a random number, at the moment I'm assume it takes the additional calculations below the above line into account before printing the answer.

My question, is how do i print the answer to CA*3??

Many Thanks

```
private OnClickListener myClickListener = new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try{
        NS=Double.parseDouble(num1.getText().toString()); 
        CH=Double.parseDouble(num2.getText().toString());
        CA=Double.parseDouble(num3.getText().toString());
        Z=Double.parseDouble(num4.getText().toString());
        EKW=Double.parseDouble(num5.getText().toString());
        FAT=Double.parseDouble(num6.getText().toString());
        CART=Double.parseDouble(num7.getText().toString());
        GAT=Double.parseDouble(num8.getText().toString());}
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            if(num1.getText().length()==0)
            {
                num1.setError("please input ");
            }
            if(num2.getText().length()==0)
            {
                num2.setError("please input ");
            }
            if(num3.getText().length()==0)
            {
                num3.setError("please ");
            }
            if(num4.getText().length()==0)
            {
                num4.setError("please ");
            }
            if(num5.getText().length()==0)
            {
                num5.setError("please input ");
            }
            if(num6.getText().length()==0)
            {
                num6.setError("please input ");
            }
            if(num7.getText().length()==0)
            {
                num7.setError("please input ");
            }
            if(num8.getText().length()==0)
            {
                num8.setError("please input ");
            }

        }

        {SV=(((NS*CH)*4)/3600)/Z;SV=(double)(Math.round(SV*100))/100; tv1.setText(Double.toString(SV));
        CARV= CA*3; tv2.setText(Double.toString(CARV));
        FA= SV*0.1;
        GA= SV - (CARV + FA);
        RCARA= CARV/SV;
        RGA= GA/SV;
        RFA= FA/SV;
        CAO=(CARV*RCARA) + (GA*RGA) + (FA*RFA);
        DT= 26-CAO;
        RKW= DT * 1.21 * SV;RKW=(double)(Math.round(RKW*100))/100; tv3.setText(Double.toString(RKW));
        }

    }
};
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.car1);

       tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView7);
       tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView8);
       tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView8);


       button01 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
       button01.setText("Display result");
       button01.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);

       num1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
       num1.setText("");
       num2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
       num2.setText("");
       num3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
       num3.setText("");
       num4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
       num4.setText("");
       num5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
       num5.setText("");
       num6 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
       num6.setText("-5");
       num7 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText6);
       num7.setText("10");
       num8 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText7);
       num8.setText("16");          
    }
```

}

Comment: Have you confirmed that the value of `CA` is what you expect?

Comment: Feel free to use whitespace a bit more generously. Your current code is somewhat bunched up in places -- in particular in the critical part -- making it somewhat difficult to read. That and non-standard naming that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is here

```
tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView8);
tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView8);
```

You assign the same TextView to `tv2` and `tv3`.

Comment: Well spotted... Silly typo to make... Thanks again.